# How to make a text-box same height as the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a text-box that has the same height as the page. For now I can only seem to make it the same height as the content I have inside the text-box. I don't know if I just haven't found the proper way to describe it with css or if it's my jQuery plugin that messes with it.

I can give it padding-top/bottom which increases the height of the text-box, but I if I give it too much padding the text gets pushed down.

The text inside the box has been given the class 'text-content' and I've applied the following css to it:

```
.text-content{
margin: auto;
width:40%;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background-color: rgba(213,213,213,0.5);
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

[Example here](http://skmo.nu/test99)

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS3, that's easily accomplished by defining a `height` of `100vh`.

```
.text-content {
    margin: auto;
    width: 40%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(213,213,213,0.5);
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3uczbe0s/

This does not take into account the `border` of the box and `margin` of the `body`, whose defaults are `1px` and `8px`, respectively. This means that using `100vh` will actually force the page to scroll. You can easily compensate by zeroing the `border` of `.text-content` and `margin` of `body`.

The only other option is to use a script to manipulate its height, which would also be backward compatible.

Comment: You also have to set the `margin` of `body` to 0 and clear the borders of `.text-content`.

Comment: @im1dermike Thank you for correcting me on that. I had noted `margin` for the box and `padding` for the `body`, but those both default to `0`. I've corrected my answer to reflect the correct attributes.