# Making the height of a div the 100% of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have the following code that I am trying to use to make the div the full height of the webpage.

HTML:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">

 <div class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
  Some content Goes Here
 </div>


<div>
```

CSS:

.page-wrapper {height: 100%;}

.vc_col-sm-6 {height: 100%; background: red;}

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1k1od3b/1/)

Comment: This same question was asked just yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838552/how-to-make-a-text-box-same-height-as-the-window/28838680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.page-wrapper {height: 100%;}

.vc_col-sm-6 {height: 100vh;
    background: red;}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  
<div class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
 Some content Goes Here
 </div>
</div>
```

give the height as

```
height: 100vh;
```

viewport height

Comment: downvote reason ?? I hate this thing at SO :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the height of the `html`, `body`, `.page-wrapper` and inner elements all 100%.

```
html,
body,
.page-wrapper,
.vc_column_container {
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .page-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
  }
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">

  <div class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column vc_column_container">
    Some content Goes Here
  </div>

  <div>
```